# Getting Dagger Component without access to Application

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger

I want to use injecting in classes like Adapter or custom object, which don't have access to MyApplication class which extends Application. 
How can I get access to component?

Is it good approach to use static methods like below?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        component = DaggerMyComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .helperModule(new HelperModule())
                .build();
    }

    public static MyComponent getComponent(){return component;}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think using static objects in this case would cause memory leaks.
What you might follow is "Inject everything" pattern shown in this [great article](http://frogermcs.github.io/inject-everything-viewholder-and-dagger-2-example/).

What is it's essence? Try to inject the object that needs `Component` inside the object that is already injected. In this article `Adapter` and `ViewHolder` (any object) is injected into activity (and objects inside adapter too). This is what you are trying to achieve.

I also advise you to read all his articles about Dagger 2, as I haven't seen such a great and advanced tutorial on Dagger 2 features